# Nagios server service_perfdata not saved at the good place

Tags: nagios, database-performance

I have a server nagios  on my Raspberry who monitored some Windows 7 client and i want to save the performance data of my service in particular file.
So i have set the nagios.cfg for it :

```
    process_performance_data=1





host_perfdata_command=process-host-perfdata-file
service_perfdata_command=process-service-perfdata-file



# HOST AND SERVICE PERFORMANCE DATA FILES
# These files are used to store host and service performance data.




host_perfdata_file=/home/pi/partage/
service_perfdata_file=/home/pi/partage/
```

But i dont see my service_perfdata_file  saved in this folder so what I missed plz ?
That folder was samba share folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value for `host_perfdata_file` and `service_perfdata_file` should be a **file name** not a **folder**. See https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html#service_perfdata_file

> ```
> Format:   service_perfdata_file=<file_name>
> Example:  service_perfdata_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata.dat
> ```

Comment: And this file name have to be  create or Nagios create it ? Because first of all, I have set this parameter like you. With a different path but it's not the point, i think..

Comment: Ok thank you I see my fichier now ! The last time I have dont specify the .dat at the end of the file name.